# How to create lists based on index or the A column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have this dataframe :

```
 A     B      C
 1     14    100
 1     15    101
 1     16    102
 2     17    103
 2     18    104
 3     19    105
 3     20    106
...   ...    ...
 n
```

and I would like this output for any number up to n for the whole dataframe :

```
l1 = [14, 15, 16] (the 1 in A column)
l2 = [17,18]  (the 2 in A column)
l3 = [19,20] (the 3 in A column)
```

Could you please help me?
Tanks !

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
l1, l2, l3 = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).values
```

Unpacking will only work only if there are three unique values in df['A'], so you probably wouldn't want to unpack the values and just index the resulting DataFrame from:

```
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list)
A
1    [14, 15, 16]
2        [17, 18]
3        [19, 20]
```